# How to find shared values among pandas dataframe rows and number of occurrences

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i'm dealing with a pretty large db, in particular with these two columns:

[image: Db columns]

First column features an id and second column values consists in lists of uids associated to the id. Uids on lists are can repeat themselves, they are not unique.
What i'm trying to do is extracting a list of tuples (or other formats, it's not mandatory) with this structure:

(inst_id1, inst_id2, shared_uids, times_each_uid_is_shared)

Where:
Shared_uids is list of uids shared, with or without duplicates;
Times_each_uid_is_shared is a dictionary {'uid': 'number of times it occurs on both uids lists'}

So, let's say i got:

`inst_1 | [uid_1, uid_2, uid_1, uid_3, uid_4]`

`inst_2 | [uid_2, uid3, uid_1, uid_5, uid_3]`

i would like to come out with:

`(inst_1, inst_2, [uid_1, uid_2, uid_3], {'uid_1': 1, 'uid_2': 1, 'uid_3': 2})`

Or some other data structure gathering the same kind of informations.

I wrote a function, the obvious one, that loops on the inst_IDs and make a set instersection between the associated uids lists, but it's pretty slow even in df.apply(lambda etc) fashion and i'm looking forward to a vectorized way of doing this task.

Thank you in advance for all the suggestions.
Stay safe,
Alessandro

Answer (score 1):

True, `df.apply()` can become extremely slow when it comes to large datasets.  There is a library called Bodo which uses high-performance computing under the hood to speed up Pandas code. It works very well with user-defined functions. Here is an example: https://medium.com/bodo-ai/making-pandas-dataframe-apply-faster-with-bodo-bbae1c485bdf

Here is the link to the installation of Bodo: https://docs.bodo.ai/latest/source/getting_started.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will give it a try.